Dynamically inject secret in docker compose
My docker compose
    version: '3.9'
    services:
     test:
       secrets:
         - source: impKey
        
    secrets:
      impKey:
        file: somePath/cred.txt

Works fine, when I have a cred file in path. I am looking to dynamically inject the value as secrets.
Other option->
secret:
    impKey:
       extend: True

Problem is, we have to create secret separately. (Not part of stack ).
Is there any other option?

Im not 100% sure what you are asking of here, but the simplest solution for swarm is to create secret with docker secret create command (https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/secret/create/) and in compose you just mark it as external.
So you have to make sure secret is created before service is being deployed.
Im confused by the word "dynamically".
